# org.eclipse.babel labels displayed in the wrong language

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Our RCP client application has german and french translations. For all the standard commands like Delete or Cancel we include the org.eclipse.babel. Most of the time this works fine and delete menu items or cancel buttons are translated to german or french.

But sometimes we see this standard labels in english, while all our own translations are shown in the correct language.

[image]
[image]

We did not find any rule why this happens. We see this behaviour occasionaly on different plattforms: when we start the product in eclispe for debugging, standalone on windows, on jenkins (for automated gui tests) or even when the client is used from citrix.

We have a target plattform definition which includes:

```
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
    <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/technology/babel/update-site/R0.20.0/2022-12/"/>
    <unit id="org.eclipse.babel.nls_eclipse_de.feature.group" version="4.26.0.v20230220105658"/>
    <unit id="org.eclipse.babel.nls_eclipse_fr.feature.group" version="4.26.0.v20230220105658"/>
    <unit id="org.eclipse.babel.nls_eclipse_it.feature.group" version="4.26.0.v20230220105658"/>
</location>
```

We define a menu entry with the standard delete command in the plugin.xml like this:

```
<command commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete">
    <visibleWhen checkEnabled="true">
        <and>
            <with variable="AuftragRW">
                <equals value="AuftragRW"/>
            </with>
        </and>
    </visibleWhen>
</command>
```

We use the -nl switch up on start-up to set the language

```
-nl de_CH
```

For good measure we also set some more VM Arguments

```
-Duser.country=CH
-Duser.language=de
-Dosgi.nl=de_CH
```

Our own translations are located in the standar folder of every bundle

```
OSGI-INF
└── l10n
    ├── bundle.properties (german translations)
    ├── bundle_fr.properties
    └── bundle_it.properties
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: The translation packages are not complete, and this is because there a many companies that build Eclipse-based applications consuming language packages but do not contribute to them. In the early days of Eclipse, there were complete language packages donated by IBM. But that was years ago. With the [pseudo translations](https://download.eclipse.org/technology/babel/babel_language_packs/latest/index.php#en_AA) language packs you can find out whether the string has be externalized and if so, the keys of the strings.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. I checked for the org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete command and it's available in the german translation of babel. Important: In 99% of all "runs" the client shows the correct labels in german. But in 1% they are missing (or not used).

Comment: Use the pseudo translations language pack to track it down. Is this reproducible in the Eclipse SDK? You might have code that sets the language programmatically (when it happens, check whether _Window > New Window_ is also affected).

Comment: No it's not reproducible. The translation is clearly there. But for some reason it is not always used.